# The probability of i errors in specified positions

Tags: coding-theory

In a binary code of length n

p(exactly i errors in specified positions)=$t^i (1-t)^{n-i}$.

I have an example where $C=\{000,111\}$, the binary repetition code of length 3.

Suppose 111 is transmitted.

Then the received words will be decoded as 111 are
${111,011,101,110}$

Why does P$($decoding as $111$ $)$= $(1-t)^3+3t(1-t)^2$ ?

Comment: I assume that the first probability should read $t^i(1-t)^{n-i}$?  But why can't $001$,say, decode to $111$?  Just needs two errors. Why do you suppose that there can't be more than one error?

Comment: This is not conditional probability,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(decoded as 111 ) = P(111 transmitted) + P(one zero transmitted)

Assuming probability of transmitting zero is $t$ we have

P(111 transmitted) = $ (1-t)^3$

P(one zero transmitted) =  ${3}\choose{1}$ $ t (1-t)^2 $

Comment: Should p(one zero transmitted) not be p( one one zero transmitted)?

Comment: I meant by one zero transmitted : { 011 or 101  or 110}, does that answer your comments? I think I can modify the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I understand now, thanks.